# How to mock firebase firestore using jest with @react-native-firebase/firestore

Tags: firebase, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, react-native-testing-library

I'm new to testing and I'm trying to fake a document update call using Jest. To do so I'm using react-native-testing-library and react-native-firebase.

Below is my test suite. I have one input, and when I'm changing its value the document should be updated

```
import firestore from "@react-native-firebase/firestore"

jest.mock("@react-native-firebase/firestore", () => {
        return () => ({
            collection: jest.fn(() => ({
                doc: jest.fn(() => ({
                    update: jest.fn(),
                })),
            })),
       });
 });

describe("<EditInfosStudy>", () => {
    const willSave = true;
    const setDidChanged = jest.fn();

    test("will update", async () => {
        const { getByTestId } = render(
            <EditInfosStudy willSave={willSave} setDidChanged={setDidChanged} />
        );

        const input = getByTestId("EditInfosStudy_TextInput");
        fireEvent.changeText(input, "study text");
        expect(input.props.value).toBe("study text");

       //  expect(firestore().collection('collection').doc('doc').update({})).toHaveBeenCalled() 
       //  this is where i'm stuck
    });
});
```

After Running the test Jest indicate a console.log from the function (below) to confirm that the document was updated and the test passes.

What I don't understand is how do I check if the document were updated on the last line using the expect method `expect(firestore()…)`  I’m really confused on the whole mocking part, any help would be greatly appreciated!

belove is the function being called :

```
if (localChange && willSave) {
        (async () => {
            try {
                await firestore()
                    .collection("users")
                    .doc(user.uid)
                    .update({ study });
                setUser({ study });
                console.log("study updated");
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
        })();
    }
```